# PHP variable isn't working for height and width

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

 var viewportwidth;
 var viewportheight;

 // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
 {
      viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
      viewportheight = window.innerHeight
 }

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

 else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
     'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
 {
       viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
 }

 // older versions of IE

 else
 {
       viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
 }

//-->
</script>
    <?php 
        $sizeh = '<script type="text/javascript">
          document.write(viewportheight);</script>';
        $sizew = '<script type="text/javascript">
          document.write(viewportwidth);
    </script>';
    ?>
</head>

//...

    <?php

<iframe  id="frame2" src="'.$row['url'].'" height="<script type=\'text/javascript\'>document.write(viewportheight);</script>px" width="'.$sizew.'px"  ></iframe> ';

?>
```

// The above still can't handle changing the values of height and width

Passing the above values from the script to iframe isn't working although printing the variables shows that they have values inside them

```
echo $sizeh; // shows ex:1093
echo $sizew; // shows ex:900
```

Anyone please assist !!!

Comment: PHP and Javascript do not interact that way. When you `echo`ed  your variables out, the Javascript got placed into the page and later executed at that position. The PHP variables themselves never had those values.

Comment: You do know that php and javascript are two completely distinct entities right? You can't "call" one from the other. The php executes first (completely) on the server, and then the javascript runs on the client. The two languages never communicate (except via ajax, but that's a special thing).

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot wrong here.

First, you can't mix PHP and JavaScript together like that. All PHP is processed *before* it's sent to the browser, and all JavaScript is processed *after* being sent to the browser. All you're doing is assigning those *literal strings* to `$sizeh` and `$sizew`. Those variables will *not* contain the viewport sizes, as those values can only be created by JavaScript, which happens *after* your PHP code runs.

Also, you can't use PHP variables outside of PHP. Once you end PHP parsing with `?>`, you are no longer in PHP and the variables can no longer be accessed.

You need to echo out your PHP variables from within a `<?php` and `?>` tags. For example:

```
<iframe  id="frame2" 
         src=" <?php echo $row['url']; ?>" 
         height="<?php echo $sizeh; ?> px" 
         width="<?php echo $sizew; ?> px"  
         >
</iframe>
```

But again, those variables don't have what you think they have in them. You either need to set those variables to have integer values from within PHP, or you need to scrap the whole thing and set the `iframe` dimensions using *only* JavaScript.

Edit: I'm not great with JavaScript, so there is almost definitely a better way of doing this (**cough** [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) **cough**), but this should work well enough:

First, you need to create a JavaScript function inside of a `<script>` block in your `<head>` section. Name it something like `resize_iframe`. In this function, you will capture the `<iframe>` element and set its size:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resize_iframe() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("my_iframe");
    iframe.style.height = viewportheight + "px";
    iframe.style.width  = viewportwidth  + "px";
  }
</script>
```

Next, in your `<body>` section, you will create your HTML page as normal. The two things to be careful of here are when you're making your `<iframe>` element, you need to:

- Make sure you give the element an id value that is the same as the one you used in the JavaScript function
- When setting the `src` attribute on the iframe, you need to remember to wrap the PHP echo in `<?php` and `?>` tags

Like this:

```
<iframe id="my_iframe"
        src="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>"
></iframe>
```

Finally, you want to call your `resize_iframe` function from a `<javascript>` block that occurs after the rest of the document is loaded. For example, put it right before the closing `</body>` tag for the document. That way, the browser will have already created the `<iframe>` element you're capturing, so it will exist for the JavaScript to modify. When that function runs, it will resize the `<iframe>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> resize_iframe(); </script>
</body>
```

One more thing: I'm not sure where you're getting the values for `viewportwidth` and `viewportheight`, but those aren't built-in variables for JavaScript. I can only assume you have other code that creates these values. If not, you will need to write it.

Comment: Well, this is better then everything else I have seen on this question so far, but it still fails to answer the question. Providing an example on HOW to use JavaScript only to set the iFrame's width and Height would be a great step to making this the best answer out here by far.

Comment: Expanding on the last part might be more helpful than the PHP code snippet.

Comment: @Mario I'm not great with JavaScript, so I didn't even try to add that code. If you want to write it up in your own answer, I'll delete this one.

Comment: @Mario: I've added a JS Example. Does this look good enough to you?

Answer (score 0):

I think that as your variables have " in them , you're ending up with:

```
<iframe  id="frame2" src="'.row['ur;'].'"
height="<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(viewportheight);</script>px"
width="<script type="text/javascript">document.write(viewportwidth);</script>px">
</iframe>
```

so the "height" and "width" attributes only contains `<script type=` and the rest is garbage so to speak

I assume that the "`<iframe....`" line is enclosed within `<?php...?>` tags and preceded by an echo of some form. If not, you're in more trouble

PS - sorry about the formatting

Comment: -1: You are also missing the point, you can't mix JavaScript and PHP like this.

Comment: @Mark: That's exactly what this answer showcases. It's not much of a solution, but sufficient as explanation.

Comment: @mario, `"'.row['ur;'].'"` still will not be parsed, and that's my main gripe is that it's not a complete answer because of this and it means there is still some mixing of PHP and JavaScript in a way that simply does not work.

Comment: I know you can't mix it hence my comment regarding enclosing the whole iframe structure within an echo command and php tags. If the code was: `<?php echo '<iframe id="frame2" src="'.row['url'].'" height="'.$sizew.'px"...</iframe>'; ?>` it would produce valid PHP but broken HTML due to the variables `$sizew` and `$sizeh` containing " and thus leaving the height and width attributes with `<script type=`. The javascript wouldn't be evaluated until the client side so the PHP variables wouldn't contain anything useful anyway

Comment: I reject that it's ok to assume that the iframe is enclosed within a php parser block. So really the assumption should be made explicit, but putting the php parser tags within the code block, as the original questioner seems not to understand the fundamentals of PHP, so that nothing can be assumed.

Comment: @Mark: That's certianly just an oversight. Not filling out that placeholder is not very relevant to the point this answer makes: the resulting HTML output is complete garbage (iframe tag intersparsed with javascript). But I think it very relevantly displays that PHP runs first, and what the outcome of that is.

Comment: @mario, ahh ... alright, I can see where you're coming from now, but I still feel like this is not really an answer. While it shows what is happening, it does not really provide an answer on what to do in order to fix it.

Comment: Mark, Mario - my bad. Sorry. I'll try better next time

Comment: <?php

<iframe  id="frame2" src="'.$row['url'].'" height="<script type=\'text/javascript\'>document.write(viewportheight);</script>px" width="'.$sizew.'px"  ></iframe> ';

?>

// The above still can't handle changing the values of height and width

Comment: This will not work - look back over the previous comments from everyone. Go back to first principles and try to get what you want to happen without PHP (hard-code some fake data for `$row['url']` and just make the page HTML) and work on it until it does what you want. If you can't get it working without PHP, it isn't going to work **with** PHP. As we have all said, PHP is excuted on the server and JavaScript works on the client. There is nothing in the line which requires PHP apart from `$row['url']` and that can be enclosed in its own <?php...?> section. Write a JS func to do what you need?

Comment: Basic problems with your code: 1 - you are not enclosing the <iframe...> structure in an echo command. 2 - the $sizeh and $sizew variables will **never** contain what you are expecting as they are being executed on the server and not the client. 3 - your JavaScript retrieving the document size is broken as it is malformed with incorrect quotes. Try running the resultant HTML through a syntax checker (like HTMLtidy or even the "Inspect Element" option in Opera) and go from there. Once you have done that, you should be in a better position to fix it all

Answer (score -1):

php can only be used between php tags you need to type

`<?php echo $sizeh; ?>`

or

`<?=$sizeh;?>`

if your host supports short tags.

Comment: You're missing the point. You simply can't Mix JavaSCript and PHP like this! The Value of `$sizeh` is always going to be the string `<script type="text/javascript">document.write(viewportheight);</script>;` And the second set of code he posted is simply not going to be parsed at all because it does not have the php parser tags around it.

Comment: Well the question is why he can't print his PHP variable. Obviously because he doesn't print it out. I assume that the javascript is in a php file part of an html page where PHP is used. so the answer to his question is to echo it.